# How to pass struct mappings to solidity functions?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

I have two mappings `(uint => customStruct)` called `listA` and `listB`.  I want to run both through a single function to perform operations on the contents.

How do I pass this type into a function so that I can call `someFunction(listA)` and `someFunction(listB)`?

I get errors like `Type is required to live outside storage`.

Comment: Ok, so I have found this which sounds related.. [data-storage](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/types.html#data-location)

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer (instead of a comment) and include details, not just a link.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't found a solution yet. The link was just a "might help" addition.

Comment: It's worth noting that you cannot iterate over a `mapping` nor can you check whether a key exists in a mapping.  In solidity, mappings exist as if every key was present and had zero's as all of it's values.

Answer (score 4):

All storage variables declared in a contract are available within the scope of all of the functions of that contract.  You do not need to pass them into your contracts functions to access them.

Answer (score 4):

I got confirmation from Chriseth that this is probably a bug in Solidity that is not allowing a mapping to be sent as a parameter.

I worked around the problem by wrapping the parameter in a struct, and of course you need to use the storage keywork.

```
someFunction(myStruct storage myInstance){}
```

Comment: I'm getting a similar error now. Is it possible this bug still exists? Is there a tracking issue in github somewhere?