# A solidity function to accept two mappings and return a single combined map

Tags: solidity, storage, mapping, struct

I've been attempting to implement a function to combine two mappings into a single one:

```
contract Mappulator {
    mapping(address => int256) public BigMap;
    struct mapper { mapping (address => int256) map;}

    function MappingCombiner(mapper map1, mapper map2){ 
        BigMap = map1.map + map2.map;
    }
}
```

According to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7757/820) I must wrap the mappings in structs to be able to pass them to a function. With the above code I get the following error:

```
Internal type is not allowed for public or external functions.
function MappingCombiner(mapper map1, mapper map2){ 
                         ^---------^
```

If I add the storage keyword, as suggested [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1390/820), I get:

```
Location has to be memory for publicly visible functions (remove the "storage" keyword).    
function MappingCombiner(mapper storage map1, mapper storage map2){ 
                         ^-----------------^
```

The compiler is not getting as far as `BigMap = map1.map + map2.map;` for me to assess if that is valid. I'm assuming not because, to combine them, both maps would have to be iterated over, which is [not straight-forward](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#mappings). Also, [it doesn't look like any operator is defined to do this](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/721b6a969685e99078e296d88135ef84f6c001eb/libsolidity/ast/Types.h#L991).

Where am I going wrong here? Would I be better off defining/converting to arrays?

**Can any provide/point to a working example of mappings being passed to a funtion and combined?**

Comment: You can't iterate over maps. The correct way to implement this is just to create a function that checks both maps and returns the non-zero result. Why do you want to combine the mappings anyway? Would some other data structure make more sense here?

Comment: @TjadenHess Thanks, but how would I check for non-zero results without iterating? It would be convenient. I have got around it by  creating a struct an array of mappings and an array of all the keys in both..

Comment: I really can't help more unless I know some context. I can just tell you that in general, iterating over potentially large data structures in Ethereum is dangerous. It's much better to update state incrementally and only when required

Comment: You cannot combine  mappings, as they can grow to such a large size that the copy operation would exceed the block's gas limit or become a DoS vector.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/24519/3573

Answer (score 3):

the problem is not about storage or memory but about using a struct as a parameter. to avoid the first problem declare your function `internal` :

```
 function MappingCombiner(mapper  map1, mapper map2) internal{ 
     }
```

for the mapping assignation I don't know what do you try to do, your operation is erroneous. the operator + is for  LValue (i.e. a variable or something that can be assigned to)